# How to calculate age in days and seconds?

Tags: php, date

I just searched, didn't get what i need.

I just want to convert the age in days like

> 20123 days

and in seconds like

> 432344344 seconds

.
How can i do it?

If i get the solution to days, i can divide it for seconds.

--- I am looking for PHP solution

Comment: Which language? Many languages have built-in ways to handle this.

Comment: in which technology are you using PHP or other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [date difference with leap year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660012/date-difference-with-leap-year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP

```
$birthday = '1989-03-06';
$now = date("Y-m-d");
echo 'You are '. date_diff(date_create($birthday), date_create($now))->format('%a days old');
```

Answer (score 2):

- A year has 365 days
- A day has 24 hours
- An hour has 60 minutes
- A minute 60 seconds

So you have to multiply.

In order to knosw if it is a leap yer, you can use this pseudo code:

```
if year modulo 4 is 0
   then
       if year modulo 100 is 0
           then
               if year modulo 400 is 0
                   then
                       is_leap_year
               else
                   not_leap_year
       else is_leap_year
else not_leap_year
```

Comment: An hour has 60 minutes and a minute has 60 seconds, just to correct you ;)

Answer (score 1):

To be super accurate you need to accountfor the leap year:

```
function get_age($dob_day,$dob_month,$dob_year){
    $year   = gmdate('Y');
    $month  = gmdate('m');
    $day    = gmdate('d');
     //seconds in a day = 86400
    $days_in_between = (mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year) - mktime(0,0,0,$dob_month,$dob_day,$dob_year))/86400;
    $age_float = $days_in_between / 365.242199; // Account for leap year
    $age = (int)($age_float); // Remove decimal places without rounding up once number is + .5
    return $age;
}
```

then to use it:

```
echo get_date(31, 01, 1985);
```

You can do additional math on the $age_float to convert it to seconds if you need.

Answer (score 0):

What programming language?

In C#:

```
var begin = new DateTime("1970/01/01");
var end = new DateTime("2011/01/01");

TimeSpan diff = end - begin;

var days = diff.Days
var seconds = diff.TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

C#

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime birthday = new DateTime(year, month, date);
TimeSpan diff = today - birthday;
MessageBox.Show(diff.TotalDays.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the birth date and time with precision. I am not sure it makes sense: babies take several minutes to born.

Then you convert the birth date & time to a time measure (that is something like the Unix `time_t` seconds measured from the Epoch, ie. jan 1st 1970 0:00 GMT).

And you can get the current time as a `time_t`

Then substract, you have the age in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're not too worried about small inaccuracies<sup>(a)</sup>, there are 365.2425 days in a year on average and 86,400 seconds in a day.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Once a child reaches the age of one, the error rate has already dropped to a maximum of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>365</sub> or 0.3%. At my ripe old age, it's way down at 0.006% so not worth even worrying about :-)